# What is the main difference between the main network code and the non-main network code

Tags: mainnet

What is the main difference between the mainnet code and the non-main network code,thanks!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

The code used for the MainNet and other networks, such as TestNets or alternate networks, is normally the same.  Some alternate networks may make alterations to the code for their specific purposes, but generally, the code is the same.

The EOS code that runs MainNet can be found on [GitHub here](https://github.com/EOS-Mainnet/eos), while the BlockOne developed source code that forms the foundation is stored in a separate [GitHub repo](https://github.com/EOSIO/eos).

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference between mainnet code and non-main code. There is only a difference in where it is deployed and executed.

Of course, if you are not testnet, you need real EOS and resources for stake.
Even so, there is no difference in code.

Answer (score 0):

While the code is exactly the same, there might be some additional system contracts deployed on a testnet that give the block producers the ability to do things that aren't possible on the mainnet. Think of pausing the blockchain, creating tokens out of thin air, and handling bandwidth, CPU and RAM allocation differently.